# Trying to use copytree to copy over subfolders recursively in Python

Tags: python, recursion, shutil, copytree

I'm working on a code that will copy over subfolders of certain directories to a new directory. I feel like I've tried everything but I can't seem to get them to copy. Only the folder and files the subfolder is located in gets copied over. Below is my code so far:

```
for cust in MULTIPLE_FOLDERS_LIST:
      if cust in clientName:
         for root, dirs, files in os.walk('\\'.join(configDir.split('\\'))):
            for direc in dirs:
               if cust in direc and not os.path.exists('\\'.join(customerConfigCustomFolderPath.split
('\\'))+'\\'+direc):
                  shutil.copytree('\\'.join(configDir.split('\\'))+'\\'+direc, '\\'.join(customerConfigCustomFolderPath.split('\\')[:-1])+'\\'+direc)
```

The locations seem to be correct (have to target the directories relatively). If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `'\\'.join(configDir.split('\\'))` ... but why? The idea of `copytree()` is that you pass *parent directory* as source argument and it recursively copies all files and subdirectories to *destination directory*, you don't need to iterate over all tree manually (*using `os.walk()`*).

Comment: "Only the folder and files the subfolder is located in gets copied over." Could you give a clear example? I don't understand how this is different from what is supposed to happen. Please show, for example, what the source folder looks like, what should happen to the destination folder after copying, and what does happen instead.

Comment: So, in the main folder there are about 8 subfolders. When I try to use copytree to copy it all over only the main folder and files located in it are visible. No subfolders or files within them.

Answer (score 1):

The entire purpose of [copytree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) is to handle the directory walking for you - there is no need to `os.walk` yourself.

To filter what is copied, use the `ignore` parameter as described in the documentation.

Comment: I get that but it hasn't been. There are slight changes to the source and destination directories I want, but I understand os.walk doesn't seem to be the way. That was from a previous coder. Ignoring all of that when I try to use shutil.copytree to move over the source folder and subfolders and files contained within it only copies over the source folder with no subfolders.